# Using Factory Boy to define three interrelated models with Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, factory-boy

I'm trying to create FactoryBoy factories for three models with a complicated relationship in a Flask/SQLAlchemy site. The models are:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref
from ..shared import db


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


class OAuth(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "flask_dance_oauth"

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id), nullable=False)
    provider_user_id = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)

    user = db.relationship(
        User,
        lazy="Joined",
        uselist=False,
        backref=backref("oauth", uselist=True, lazy="select"),
    )


class TwitterUserData(db.Model):
    "Stores data about the User's twitter account."
    __tablename__ = "twitter_user_data"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_str = db.Column(db.String(191), nullable=False, unique=True)

    user = db.relationship(
        "User",
        secondary="flask_dance_oauth",
        primaryjoin="and_("
            "OAuth.provider_user_id == TwitterUserData.id_str, "
            "OAuth.provider == 'twitter'"
        ")",
        secondaryjoin="User.id == OAuth.user_id",
        uselist=False,
        lazy="select",
        viewonly=True,
        backref=backref("twitter_data", uselist=False, lazy="select"),
    )
```

To summarise the relationships:

- `User.oauth` is an `OAuth` object
- `User.id` maps to `OAuth.user_id`
- `User.twitter_data` is a `TwitterUserData` object
- `TwitterUserData.user` is a `User` object
- `TwitterUserData.id_str` maps to `OAuth.provider_user_id`

My factories are currently:

```py
import factory


class OAuthFactory(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = OAuth
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session
        sqlalchemy_session_persistence = "commit"


class TwitterUserDataFactory(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = TwitterUserData
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session
        sqlalchemy_session_persistence = "commit"

    id_str = factory.Sequence(lambda n: (n * 1000000000000000))


class UserFactory(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session
        sqlalchemy_session_persistence = "commit"

    twitter_data = factory.SubFactory(TwitterUserDataFactory)

    oauth = factory.SubFactory(
        OAuthFactory,
        user_id=factory.SelfAttribute("..id"),
        provider_user_id=factory.SelfAttribute("..twitter_data.id_str"),
    )
```

Using this, `oauth.user_id` can't be set because "The parameter 'id' is unknown."

Instead I tried this to define `oauth`, in the hope that in `post_generation` the user would have an `id`:

```py
    @factory.post_generation
    def oauth(obj, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            return
        oauth = oauth_factory(
            user_id=obj.id,
            provider_user_id=obj.twitter_data.id_str
        )
        return oauth
```

But here `obj.twitter_data` is a `'NoneType' object`, which puzzles me.

I'm not sure what else to try.